# Proteus Autorouter Not Using Ground Plane

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, proteus

I've created a ground plane on my Proteus schematic but for some reason the autorouter is totally ignoring it and trying to link all of the ground connections with traces.

How do I fix this and force the autorouter to use the ground plane?

Comment: Please add a screenshot.

Comment: have you used zone mode ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

1. Go to zone mode and select the area of PCB.
2. Select NET as GND.
3. Select Allow nesting.
4. Select your desired layer.

Then you won't face this problem. If you want, you may comment your email then I can send you the video of the process.

Look the connection is mixed with the ground plane. It won't be visible if you print bottom copper.
[image]

Comment: Hi Sadat, that doesn't seem to work

Comment: But it's working in my screenshot. Look at the hole. The GND terminal is connected to the ground plane.

Comment: include a screenshot of your project

Comment: Looking at your screenshot, it's still routing a GND trace on the bottom copper rather than just dropping to the ground plane? I'm sorting you a screenshot now

Comment: that is mixed in the ground plane. It's not a different line.

Comment: I've added another picture.

Comment: Ahh okay, weird how it's still drawn them... Thanks man!